# Treat NaN's as NULL in SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to load a large `.txt` file into a table in an `SQL Server 2012` database through a `SSIS package`, I have created through the `SQL Server Import Wizard`.

Some of my numeric columns contain a few "NaN" text values, and I would like them to be converted to `NULL`. I just don't know how specify this in the wizard nor in the saved `SSIS package`.

Note: The `.txt` file is too big for me to replace "NaN" with blanks (I can't install any program like `Notepad++` on my computer), and then enabling `RetainNulls`.

Is it possible to specify that "NaN" should be read as 'NULL'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going with package, in data flow use derived column and in that use replace function

```
        replace('NAN',column,null)
```

Or if you want to change data in database you can use update statement in "OLEDB command" transformation

```
Update table
set column_name=null
where column_name='NAN'
```

Comment: Do you mean that I start by importing the columns as text strings, then use ´replace('NAN',column,null)´ and then changing the column type to numeric? I ask because right now I cannot even load the data - I get errors, and I don't see how your solutions help on this...?

Comment: if that available in database, then use update.... Or in flat file then go with replace function and again upload it